# Multiple Pages in Jasper Report with different table contents

Tags: java, jaspersoft-studio

Guys. I've been developing a school management system with java, MySQL and TIBCO Jasper Studio. But I've stuck in a certain point in generating a report.
Here is my scenario.

1. I have two tables called "Student Details" and "Student Results".
2. In Student Details got "Student ID, Student Name" further Student Results got "Student ID, Subject Name, Grade".
3. In fact I have successfully managed to populate data in single page in Jasper Studio with Java Code for a single student for showing his/her exam results.
4. Though, my real requirement is when I give a range of students I want to populate a Jasper Report with multiple pages for given range of students to show their exam results (Grade) in each page as picture.

[image]

5. How ever I managed to populate each page separately for each student. Though results of all students which I select are showing in first page under first student and not showing other students pages.

[image]

My method of data populating to report is JRTableModelDataSource for Report page and Report table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with following solution,

short the dataset used by Student ID in SQL query as follows,

```
SELECT student_details.student_id, student_details.student_name, student_results.subject, student_results.grade FROM student_details INNER JOIN student_results ON student_details.student_id = student_results.student_id ORDER BY student_details.student_id
```

create a group based on `student_id` field and set `isStartNewPage` property to true,

field of `student_id`

```
<field name="student_id" class="java.lang.Integer">
    ......
</field>
```

group of `student_id`

```
<group name="student_id" isStartNewPage="true">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{student_id}]]></groupExpression>
</group>
```